# can i use two routes.MapRoute in route.config in mvc and why

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NewEmp", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NewEmp", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Has my answer helper you? Was it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add multiple routes.

However you can't add two routes with the same name (in your case "Default").

Reason why you are able to add and use multiple routes is a broad issue. To cut a long story short - you can need other routing patterns for a particular area or controller. The routing allows you to implement flexible web applications which use URL exactly as you want, for instance:

Routing pattern: {country}-{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
URL: ~/us-en/products/show/123

Please keep in mind you have to add the most detailed routes first because the ASP.MVC mechanisms tries to fit the URL to routes from first to last as they're defined in RouteConfig.cs.